# How to create dynamic log files in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

I am having multiple company login in my application. I need separate activity log for companies. I am unable to create it in bootstrap as i am not getting session there.

Kindly suggest how to proceed?

Is it right to configure log in controller's action?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->log("Write your content here","Write your dynamic file Name here");
```

Comment: i got the log file, but  how can i implement basic log file rotation ?

Comment: `basic log file rotation` means what?

Comment: @Vaibhav Read the book, it's described there http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/logging.html.

Comment: You should let the server handle log rotation.